# Проигнорированный флаг JavaScript

Tags: javascript

В простом тексте вздумалось мне найти буквосочетания:

```js
var text = "Просто прекрасно как я прусь с простого языка JavaScript";

    alert ( text.search( /ПР/ ));
    alert ( text.search( /ПР/i ));
    alert ( text.search( /ПР/g ));
```

В результате все алерты выдают -1.

Я ожидаю 0 , 6 ... и т.д.

Comment: второй выдает 0 - как и положено. остальные выдают -1 как и должно быть...... `i` - не зависит от регистра.... `g` - ищет везде .. а теперь посмотри на свой код

Comment: Все включилось когда сохранил файл с указанием UTF-8, Всем спасибо за внимание!

Comment: один момент! можно объявлять больше одного флага за раз? вроде  /ПР/i,g...?

Comment: В данном случае кроме `i` бесполезно ставить тот же `g` флаг.. ибо поиск все равно глобальный, но по умолчанию регистрозависимый.... с регистрозависимом поиском вообще проще писать `text.search('Пр')`

Comment: Как же быть если необходимо искать не зависимо то регистра но глобально?

Comment: использовать регулярку, а не `search`, очевидно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Метод [`search`](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-methods#str-search-reg) возвращает позицию первого совпадения или -1, если
>   ничего не найдено. Ограничение метода `search` – он всегда ищет только
>   первое совпадение. Нельзя заставить `search` искать дальше первого
>   совпадения, такой синтаксис попросту не предусмотрен.

```js
var text = "Просто прекрасно как я прусь с простого языка JavaScript";

alert(text.search(/ПР/)); // -1 - ничего не найдет из-за регистра
alert(text.search(/ПР/i)); // 0 - найдет первое (i - не учитывая регистр)
alert(text.search(/ПР/g)); // -1 - ничего не найдет из-за регистра
alert(text.search(/ПР/ig)); // 0 - только 0 (из-за специфики 'search', 'g'-не влияет) 
alert(text.search(/Пр/)); // 0 - найдет первое учитывая регистр
alert(text.search(/пр/g)); // 7 - первое, учитывая регистр ('g'-не влияет на 'search')
```

> Регулярные выражения могут иметь [флаги](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-introduction#%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8), которые влияют на поиск. В
>   JavaScript их три:
>
> - `i` - если этот флаг есть, то регэксп ищет независимо от регистра, то    есть не различает между А и а.
> - `g` - если этот флаг есть, то регэксп ищет все совпадения, иначе –    только первое.
> - `m` - многострочный режим.

На заметку ссылка для ознакомления: [регулярные выражения](https://learn.javascript.ru/regular-expressions-javascript).

Ну и на последок простой пример поиска всех совпадений в строке с использованием `RegExp` (наша регулярка, текст, ну и в цикле пробежим, пока есть совпадения будем добавлять их в результирующий массив, а затем выведем на экран найденные индексы):

```js
var regex = /ПР/ig,
  text = "Просто прекрасно как я прусь с простого языка JavaScript",
  match,
  indices = [];

while (match = regex.exec(text)) {
  indices.push(match.index);
}
alert(indices);
```

Comment: Денис, огромное спасибо!! Очень полный и развернутый ответ. Вы мне сильно помогли, благодарю :)